# Check if php-cgi server is connectable remotely

Tags: php

I have a php server listening on a port that seems to have issues. How can I connect to the php-cgi server to find out it if it up or not? (Sort of "ping" the php-cgi process)

I need to determine if the issue I'm having is due to the http server or the php-cgi server. Therefor I want to be able to "ping" the php-cgi server to make sure it is accepting requests. If not, I know it is the php-cgi server that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: can you not just telnet on that port?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use telnet

telnet localhost portnumber.

So if you running on port 80 of your localhost type in

> telnet localhost 80

It should connect if it does not, your server is not running!